# SQL03006 error in VS2010 Database Project (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, project

When I try to set up a database project for SQL Server 2008 in VS2010 I keep running into error "SQL03006 - Column xyz contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects ..."

One example with the original code would be as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSomeView]
AS
SELECT 
    CT.ID, 
    CT.UserName, 
    ST.Title
FROM
    SomeOtherDatabase.dbo.ComputerTable CT
JOIN
    SomeOtherDatabase.dbo.SoftwareTable ST ON
    CT.ID = ST.ComputerID
```

Now the error only refers to e.g. column CT.UserName, not CT.ID. I also added a corresponding database reference to "SomeOtherDatabase" and updated the code as recommended by several posts I found during my search for a solution:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSomeView]
AS
SELECT 
    CT.ID, 
    CT.UserName, 
    ST.Title
FROM
    [$(SomeOtherDatabaseName)].dbo.ComputerTable CT
JOIN
    [$(SomeOtherDatabaseName)].dbo.SoftwareTable ST ON
    CT.ID = ST.ComputerID
```

What I don't understand is why there is a problem with one column from the CT table, but not the other. When I look at the table definition in the database project, all seems to be fine as the column is there (as expected).

I'm also not quite sure whether I can refer to the table names by their alias once that is defined, i.e. do I have a problem writing "CT.ComputerID" instead of "[$(SomeOtherDatabaseName)].dbo.ComputerTable" (I don't think so, but I keep running into so many errors that I feel a little bit lost at the moment).

Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated, thank you.

**Update**

The actual error message is like:

```
SQL03006: View: [dbo].[vwSomeView] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [$(SomeOtherDatabaseName)].[dbo].[ComputerTable]::[ID] or [$(SomeOtherDatabaseName)].[dbo].[SoftwareTable]::[ID]"
```

G.

Comment: Can you post the actual message that matches the code you'e posted please? Why sanitise the error when you have given code: or have you give us sanitised code too...?

Comment: It's an amended version that is less verbose than the original code, although hopefully still showing the general problem that I run into. If need be I think I can set up a complete example with suitable code to create the databases and tables, but that would probably be a lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN is `SoftwareTable .ComputerID` to on `ComputerTable.ID` which implies to me that there is no `ComputerID` column in `ComputerTable` (the CT alias)

Do you *really* have a `ComputerTable.ComputerID` column in addition to `ComputerTable.ID`? Which is the unique key for the foriegn key on `SoftwareTable`?

The `[$(SomeOtherDatabaseName)]` bit is a red herring I think

Edit:

Your error is caused by SQL Server looking for a database name `[$(SomeOtherDatabaseName)]`

It isn't being corrcted by VS for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error. The table relationship is like "usual", CT.ID = ST.ComputerID. The [$(SomeOtherDatabaseName)] syntax I've met a couple of times though, I think I need it as soon as I reference another database project.

Comment: ..and the actual error please now? You still mention CT.ComputerID in your question too...

Comment: Updated, hope this helps. If not I will try to create some sample code, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, but according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bahill/archive/2009/08/26/using-self-referencing-or-local-3-part-names.aspx this would mean that I cannot use VS2010 for Database Projects as soon as there are links between different databases. If I don't use the [$(DatabaseName)] syntax, VS2010 cannot handle it, but if I do it also doesn't work.

Comment: The article says "Our guidance is to not use local 3-part names as it introduces an unnecessary layer of abstraction and dependency on the database name." Too right. The fact is that VS is not substituting the name on deployment. You can trap this error earlier by using WITH SCHEMABINDING: SQL Server won't allow view creation if references can not be resolved

Comment: I still don't get it. Fair enough, I don't want to state the whole multiple part identifier for local objects when the script already is in that particular database. But as soon as it is in a different one, I need multiple parts for the identifier, and the [$(...)] syntax as far as I understood is only to guarantee that the deployment of the scripts will work as expected? Unfortunately I have a server full of legacy databases (not my own of course, as such things usually are), and they are all dependent on each other.

Comment: VS isn't updating the reference on deployment. Simple. Now, you have to resolve this (did you follow the article *exactly*?) or don't use this "feature".